# Amd Radeons Overscan is reset after every boot

Tags: ati, radeon

I have an AMD Radeon 6850 in my set up which is connected to my monitor via an hdmi cable. After installing the latest fglrx drivers, version 12.6, I need to drag the overscan slider all the way to the right to make the desktop properly fit my monitor. But now after every reboot the overscan image is very small and there is about a 2 inch large border around my display. When I open Catalyst Control Center the overscan slider is still as far to the right as possible, but when I slide it all the way to the left and then to the right again it fits my screen perfectly. How to I stop this small inconvenience?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. So annoying as I was using this on my HTPC now requires a mouse for every boot -.-

Also the latest 12.6 fglrx from AMD site with an AMD Radeon HD 5450. Ubuntu 12.04 minimal + gnome3-core.

Comment: Did you open catalyst with admin permissions? I have 2 options: one as a normal user and one as admin. You must use the 2nd one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the following:

```
sudo amdconfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0
```

Then reboot.

Comment: PCS commands can only be performed by root

Comment: You are. My hero.

Comment: If using the `fglrx-driver` package: `sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0`

Answer (score 5):

I used @user188647 's answer as inspiration, but the command wasn't working.

So I edited `/etc/ati/amdpcsdb`, and in the `AMDPCSROOT/SYSTEM/MCIL` section, added:

```
DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan=V0
```

Then I shut down the X server, started it up again and voila!  No underscan.

Inspired by: https://github.com/OpenELEC/OpenELEC.tv/issues/1636

Comment: fixed ot for me, be carfeul so you dont enter anything wron here thought :)