# Catalyst Control Center 13.1 resets my HDTV scaling options after reboot

Tags: 12.10, ati, fglrx, scaling, hdtv

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10. After installing ATI 13.1 drivers, I configure ATI overscan to fit desktop to screen.
The problem is that when I reboot catalyst reset the setting. I've tried everything on internet but nothing seems fixing it. Can you help me?

Comment: Meybe it will help:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/115561/ati-catalyst-doesnt-retain-changes-after-reboot-when-setting-extended-display

Answer (score 0):

check [Amd Radeons Overscan is reset after every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166937/amd-radeons-overscan-is-reset-after-every-boot)
Also make sure that the tv settings for aspect ratio are right. For my 42" Lg tv I had to put aspect ratio for 'just scan' in combination with the above solution and problem is gone.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.